# ECS 'Component' Class in Python similar to Unity's Component class but more pure

Tags: python, entity-component-system

The following implementation seems to pass all initial requirements.
Which were as follows:

- Store all components in the root class allowing for any scope with a reference to the class
  the ability to find or lookup active components
- One reference to all components, all others would be weakref's
- Ability to create a new component via a factory method
- Unique component id's
- Grouping of all similar components for fast lookups

The goal was a fast and modular component lookup and a way to store the components that didn't have to be passed around. Again the code works in the current scope of the project however my `init` seems a bit verbose and potentially unnecessary. I'm wondering if there are any obvious flaws or bugs before I move forward and begin work on other portions of the ECS

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Dict, List, Type


class Component(object):
    """ Root Component type in an ECS system """
    _type_table: Dict[str:Type] = {}                  # Hashable ref to all Components -> {class_name:class}
    _active_comp_ref: Dict[str:List[Component]] = {}  # Ref to all active components
    _id = 0                                           # Count of every object every created

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__instance_id = None
        c_type = self.__class__
        c_name = c_type.__name__
        if c_name not in Component._type_table:                             # First time creating this type
            Component._type_table[c_name] = c_type                          # Store type
            c_type._active_comp_ref = dict()                                # Create comp ref on subclass
            Component._active_comp_ref[c_name] = c_type._active_comp_ref    # Store ourselves in ref
        self.__initialize_id()
        c_type._active_comp_ref[self.id] = self

    @staticmethod
    def get_component(type_name: str) -> Type[Component]:
        """ Return a Component type by name """
        return Component._type_table[type_name]

    @staticmethod
    def get_component_table() -> Dict[str:Dict[int:Component]]:
        """ Get the table used to store all Components """
        return Component._active_comp_ref

    @staticmethod
    def component_types() -> Dict[str:Type[Component]]:
        """ Get the Component Type Table """
        return Component._type_table

    @staticmethod
    def __next_id():
        """ Increment Core ID: Should not be called externally"""

        Component._id += 1
        return Component._id

    @property
    def id(self):
        """ Unique Instance ID Property """
        return self.__instance_id

    def __initialize_id(self):
        """ Get the next ID and remove this method """
        # Done like this to ensure id is set once and only once
        self.__instance_id = self.__next_id()
        self.__set_id = None


class Transform(Component):
    """ Basic Testing class"""
    def __init__(self, pos, direction, vel):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = pos
        self.direction = direction
        self.vel = vel


class Health(Component):
    """ Basic Testing class"""
    def __init__(self, cur_hp, max_hp):
        super().__init__()
        self.cur_hp = cur_hp
        self.max_hp = max_hp


def c_factory(name: str, **kwargs) -> Component:
    """ Create a new Component from a name and a dict of attributes """
    c = type(name, (Component, ), kwargs)
    return c()

# Basic Implementation Tests
t = Transform((100, 100), (1, 0), .1)
t2 = Transform((100, 50), (-1, 1), .2)
Health(10, 100)
f = c_factory("Renderer", surface=None, size=(100, 100))
f.surface = (500, 400, 800)
del f  # Should only delete pointer to this?
print(Component.get_component_table()["Renderer"][4].surface)  # Obviously not how I plan to do lookups but at this moment i'm not positive on the best way!
Component.get_component("Transform")((10, 10), (0, -1), .5)
print(Component.get_component_table())
```

Comment: Which is it - Python 2 or 3? And if it's 2 - why? That's been deprecated for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Beware: I'm grumpy and opinionated about dynamic types and that's going to colour this review. First I think your requirements themselves need a little commentary:

> Store all components in the root class allowing for any scope with a reference to the class the ability to find or lookup active components

Why? You have class definitions. In what reality would you have access to the base component symbol but not the symbols for your other classes e.g. `Transform`? Why would you ever have only a string name of the class? If this ever does actually happen, rather than your type table machinery, you can import the module containing the class in question and call `getattr(module, class_name)`.

> One reference to all components, all others would be weakref's

Big red flashing warning sign. This is an excellent way to defeat the garbage collector and create rampant memory leaks.

> Ability to create a new component via a factory method

Why? Creation of such a dynamic type will harm your static analysis.

> Unique component id's

Sure. Your approach, though, seems to assign globally-unique IDs where that's not strictly necessary and could be confusing. Instead, why not have an ID sequence unique to each component class? Said another way, if I dynamically create a `Renderer` class and then instantiate it, the least surprising thing would be for that first instance to start with an ID of 0 regardless of other component history.

> a way to store the components that didn't have to be passed around.

This seems like a solution to a non-problem. Passing around references is a feature, not a bug; and again if you're attempting to be tricky with references you have a perfect recipe for memory leaks.

With that out of the way, some specifics about your code:

- Don't inherit from `object` in Python 3
- Don't use double-underscores for things like `__instance_id`; those are reserved for name mangling
- Your dictionary hints are incorrect, though (bafflingly) they seem to interpret OK. `Dict[str:Type]` should be `Dict[str, Type]`.
- The fact that you increment and return your ID in a non-atomic manner means that your code is not thread-safe. I have not attempted to address this in my suggested code, mind you.
- *Should only delete pointer to this?* mischaracterizes how Python works; replacing "pointer" with "reference" will make this statement accurate.
- Why have a factory that forces you to use the dynamic type only once? Return the type, not the instance.

The following suggested code uses both a base class and a metaclass, to assign statics unique to each subclass. It includes a factory, but does away with your type table. If it were up to me, none of this should exist and if - for example - this is for a game, just do traditional reference passing.

```
from pprint import pprint
from types import new_class
from typing import Dict, Type, Tuple, Any, ClassVar, Optional


class Component:
    id_seq: ClassVar[int]
    refs: ClassVar[Dict[int, 'Component']]

    def __init__(self):
        cls = type(self)
        self.id = cls.id_seq
        cls.refs[self.id] = self
        cls.id_seq += 1


class ComponentMeta(type):
    def __new__(
        mcs: type,
        name: str,
        bases: Tuple[type, ...],
        dct: Dict[str, Any],
    ) -> Type[Component]:
        cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, (Component, *bases), dct)
        cls.id_seq = 0
        cls.refs = {}
        return cls


class Transform(object, metaclass=ComponentMeta):
    def __init__(
        self,
        pos: Tuple[int, int],
        direction: Tuple[int, int],
        vel: float,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos, self.direction, self.vel = pos, direction, vel


class Health(metaclass=ComponentMeta):
    def __init__(self, cur_hp: int, max_hp: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.cur_hp, self.max_hp = cur_hp, max_hp


def c_factory(name: str) -> Type[Component]:
    return new_class(name, kwds={'metaclass': ComponentMeta})


def test():
    t = Transform((100, 100), (1, 0), .1)
    t2 = Transform((100, 50), (-1, 1), .2)

    Health(10, 100)

    Renderer = c_factory('Renderer')
    f = Renderer()
    f.surface = None
    f.size = (100, 100)
    f.surface = (500, 400, 800)
    print(Renderer.refs[0].surface)

    t3 = Transform((10, 10), (0, -1), .5)

    pprint(Transform.refs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```